# Javascript - For Loop key undefined ONLY for 1st iteration?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Why does this always print UNDEFINED for the first iteration of array[j]??

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
for (i in array) {

    console.log("array[i]:" +array[i]);

    for (j=i+1; j<array.length-1;j++) {

        console.log("array[j]:"+ array[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the value of `i` and you will easily spot your mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `i` contains a string value, not a number.

Setting `j` to `i+1` makes it `"0"+1`, not `0+1`, so that is `"01"`. As there is no item in `array` with the key `"01"` you get `undefined` back.

When `j++` is executed, it will convert the `"01"` into the number `1` and increase it, so that loop will run as expected to the end.

For the next iteration in the outer loop, you get `j = "11"`, and when that is compared to the length of the array it will skip the inner loop. For the rest of the iterations in the outer loop, the inner loop will be skipped as `j` will start outside of the array.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `foreach` syntax on the array, it is actually pulling the index of the array into the `i` variable as a string value.  performing `j = i + 1` sets the `j` variable to the string value `01`, for which there is no corresponding value at that key in `array` so it returns undefined.

After the first iteration in the sub-loop, `j++` will convert it to an integer and return the proper value at the index of the array.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript) for more information about the `foreach` syntax you are using.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using a `for...in` loop over an array. When you use `for...in`, array indexes are viewed as hash keys and are therefore treated as strings. So when you begin your second loop and you set `j` to `i + 1`, you have really set `j` to "01".  Since there is no `array["01"]` you get undefined for the first iteration.  Upon the second iteration, you convert `j` back to a number by setting it to `length - 1` and can therefore use it to access array indexes.  Try this example:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
for (i in array) {

    console.log(typeof i);
    console.log("array[i]:" +array[i]);

    for (j=i+1; j<array.length-1;j++) {

        console.log(j);
        console.log("array[j]:"+ array[j]);
    }
}
```

The way you fix this is by NOT using `for...in` loops with arrays. Just stick with normal `for` loops and, of course, `while` and `do` loops where situation requires.

Answer (score 0):

**The Rest of the Story**

This is a late entry in the answer race.

**Use `for..of`**

`for ( var i of array)` automatically coerces the `Array` "indexes" to numbers - **so the OP's problem is fixed simply by replacing "in" with "of"**

**Don't use `for..in`**

JS documentation says

> Note: for...in should not be used to iterate over an Array where the index order is important.

Why? All the current answers say the problem is that the "indexes" are really strings. How is that? We all know the "for loop" uses numbers and that works.

**JS `Array`s are not arrays but regular JS objects**

A JS Array is actually a plain old JS object in disguise - Key:Value pairs where the key (property name) is always a string.  An `Array` does not have real indexes! The "indexes" are just properties who's names are stringed-numbers, so "0", "1", etc. There are no numeric indexes. But you can say `Array` is a special case of JS objects - it uses invalid names (starts with a digit) and JS allows us to write as if `Array` actually has indexes. Just another of the many, many Javascript WTFs.