# How to iterate through an array of arrays while using an expression within the indices

Tags: javascript

When I run the below JavaScript code the first two lines of output are:

```
5
undefined
```

Why is the second output line undefined and not 5? Here is the code:

```js
matrix = [
  [2, 5, 7],
  [4, 6, 1],
  [7, 3, 9]
];
for (var i in matrix) {
  for (var j in matrix[i]) {
    console.log(matrix[0][0 + 1]);
    console.log(matrix[i][j + 1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `for...in` with arrays, it hould be used with objects, in your code both `i` and `j` are strings, so `j + 1` will not be what you expect it to be. It also loops the array out of order

Comment: Because `j` is the string `"0"`. `"0" + 1` is `"01"`, not `1`. Related: [Javascript - For Loop key undefined ONLY for 1st iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22182453/4642212).

Comment: It’s also explained here, in [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1365581/4642212).

Comment: @Xufox The link you shared solved the problem. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

oNot sure why you are trying to +1. This is causing your issue.
Also included `array.forEach` of this as well.

Included fix based on Ibrahim comment

```js
matrix = [[2, 5, 7], [4, 6, 1], [7, 3, 9]];
for(let i of  matrix){
    for(let j of i){
        console.log(j);
    }
}

matrix.forEach(m => {
  m.forEach(e => console.log(e));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast your j variable to integer using Number() function.

```js
matrix = [
  [2, 5, 7],
  [4, 6, 1],
  [7, 3, 9]
];
for (var i in matrix) {
  for (var j in matrix[i]) {
    console.log(matrix[0][0 + 1]);
    console.log(matrix[i][Number(j) + 1]);
  }
}
```